# Factorization of an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $f$ be analytic in $\Omega$. Assume $P\in\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$ is a polynomial whose irreducible factors are all of multiplicity one.

If $f$ vanishes on the zero set $Z(P)$ of $P$, how to justify that $f/P$ is analytic in $\Omega$ ?

Comment: For $n > 1$, $P$ doesn't factorize but squarefree still makes sense. I'd say those are the gaps to be filled :

$Z(P)= \bigcup U_j$ where $I(U_j) = \{Q\in\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n], Q|_{U_j} = 0\}$ are prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$. Because the $U_j$ are hypersurfaces those prime ideals are principal $I(U_j) =(R_j)$ and $I(Z(P)) = I(U_1)\cap \ldots \cap I(U_m) = \sqrt{(P)}$. That $P$ is square-free means $\sqrt{(P)} = (P)$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is simply connected $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$ is dense in $A(\Omega)$ the ring of analytic functions on $\Omega$. Let $I(U_j)_A = \{ f \in A,f|_{U_j} = 0\}$ they are not prime ideals but they stay generated by $R_j$ so $f|_{Z(P)}= 0$ iff $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ where the $f_n$ are polynomials $ \in I(U_1)\cap \ldots \cap I(U_m)$ so $f_n/P$ is a sequence of polynomials and since it converges to a meromorphic function $f/P$ it must be analytic. If $\Omega$ is not simply connected it is some localization of $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$  which is dense and the idea is similar.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the comments. As far as I can see, it seems to me that some arguments are still missing to derive a proof.

Comment: The main point should be that $I(U_j)_A$ stays a principal ideal generated by $R_j$ : if $f \in I(U_j)_A$ (and $\Omega$ simply connected) approximate it by polynomials $F_m$ then $Z(F_m)$ is closed to $U_j$ so you can approximate it by an element of $I(U_j)$ thus of the form $G_m R_j$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could argue stalk wise. Take a point $x \in \Omega$. By general theory, the ring of convergent power series at $x$, $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n, x}$, is a UFD. Since $P$ is square-free, and $f$ vanishes at $\{P =0\}$, $P$ is a factor of $f$ in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$ by the analytic Nullstellensatz. So there is a quotient $\overline{g_x} = f/P$ in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$. This is represented by an actual holomorphic function $g_x \in \mathcal O(U_x)$ in some neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$, and $g_x \cdot P = f$ holds on all of $U_x$. By the identity theorem, the $g_x$ glue to a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$.

---

Note however, that the ring $\mathcal O(\Omega)$ is in general *not* a UFD. For example if $n = 1$ and $\Omega = \mathbb C$, the function $f(z) = \sin(z)$ has infinitely many irreducible factors $P_k = (z - k \pi), \,k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks ! see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441651/factorization-of-an-analytic-function-in-mathbbcn).